# Run docker command with variable substitution

Tags: docker, shell, github-actions

I'm trying to run docker pull command in github actions in a linux runner.

```
  - name: Update image tag
    run: |
        PROD_REPO="myrepo"
        #...some other code
        docker pull myorg.jfrog.io/`$PROD_REPO`-snapshot:${{ matrix.image_tag }}
```

But I'm getting error:
`myrepo: command not found`

I was expecting the command to be interpreted as:

`docker pull myorg.jfrog.io/myrepo-snapshot:latest`

Here `${{ matrix.image_tag }}` is fetched from step above, which is working.

Comment: It looks like you surrounded the variable name with backticks, which in the shell mean "execute the contents of this string as a command and substitute the output". Replace them with double quotes (`"$PROD_REPO"`) and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute one more command by adding `` `$PROD_REPO` ``. Below code snippet should work for you

```yaml
 - name: Update image tag
   run: |
        PROD_REPO="myrepo"
        docker pull myorg.jfrog.io/$PROD_REPO-snapshot:${{ matrix.image_tag }}
```